# Datagridview to CrystalReport Error "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, crystal-reports

I am trying to get the datagridview data to Crystal report, but i am getting this ERROR message "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."

Any Idea how to fix my error?

```
Sub PrintToCR()
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells("ProductID").Value, dr.Cells("BrandName").Value, dr.Cells("GenericName").Value, _
                    dr.Cells("ExpirationDate").Value, dr.Cells("Price").Value, _
                    dr.Cells("Unit").Value, dr.Cells("QuantityOnHand").Value) '<<<<< Error is HERE.
    Next
    '
    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New CrystalReport1
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)
    '
    CrystalReportViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc
    CrystalReportViewer.ShowDialog()
    CrystalReportViewer.Dispose()
End Sub
```

this is my Database transaction

```
Public Class data
Dim connString As New connection
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

Public Function List(ByVal sql As String) As DataSet
    con.ConnectionString = connString.connectionString
    con.Open()
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "data")
    con.Close()
    List = ds
End Function

Public Sub ExecuteSql(ByVal sql As String)
    con.ConnectionString = connString.connectionString
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = sql
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Btw, my Datagridview is connected via Datasource

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting Error as "input array is longer than the number of columns in this table"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350634/getting-error-as-input-array-is-longer-than-the-number-of-columns-in-this-table)

Comment: yeah, i saw this question. but the problem is i don't know how to convert or change the C# code into .net.. Can you help me identify or tell me what is exactly wrong in my code? thanks

Comment: Uhm, it's VB.NET and the text is English: *"You need to add columns to this data table first"*

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
     Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt.Columns.Add("ProductId")
    dt.Columns.Add("BrandName")
    dt.Columns.Add("GenericName")
    dt.Columns.Add("ExpirationDate")
    dt.Columns.Add("Price")
    dt.Columns.Add("Unit")
    dt.Columns.Add("QuantityOnHand")

    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows()

        dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells("ProductID").Value, dr.Cells("BrandName").Value, dr.Cells("GenericName").Value, _
                    dr.Cells("ExpirationDate").Value, dr.Cells("Price").Value, _
                    dr.Cells("Unit").Value, dr.Cells("QuantityOnHand").Value)
    Next
    '
    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New CrystalReport1
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)
    CrystalReportViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc
    CrystalReportViewer.ShowDialog()
    CrystalReportViewer.Dispose()
```